# ds-5 ultimate evaluation version supports 64bit neon ( arm_v8 neon)

Tags: arm, ds-5, armclang

I have installed the current "`DS-5 Ultimate 64-bit evaluation` " version  but am **not able to build for ARMv8 64-bit neon**.
     In **armclang** am **not able to find the cpu list it shows only option**  `"Target: aarch64-arm-none-eabi".`

please help me to solve the below issues

1. Does **this version support ARMv8 neon**?
2. How to **find available cpu list** (as in `armcc --cpu` list) or **equivalent armclang options**.

Comment: Did you try the manual? All of the [two currently-supported CPUs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0774a/chr1392632801932.html), and [the compiler](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0774a/chr1392305424052.html) support NEON (since it's a mandatory part of the v8 architecture with only a _possible_ exception for very esoteric embedded implementations, but nobody's built such a thing yet).

Answer (score 0):

`aarch64` *is* ARMv8. And NEON is mandatory in ARMv8, so it's included.